# Answering a question with a different command to solve it

Tags: discussion

Something that annoys me probably more than it should is when someone asks a question involving the syntax of a particular command, and the answers appear showing the same way of doing it with completely different commands. Using StackOverflow as a learning tool for some time now, although I perceive the value of an answer like `this won't solve your problem because of reasons, you should work with this command instead`, sometimes it is possible, and the answer only reflects the particular experience of the author.

A few examples: `How can I use sed to solve [stuff]?`, with `awk` answers. `How can I do this using LinkedList in Java?`, with answers using `ArrayLists`, `How can I solve this using pysolve?`, answers with `oct2py` package. Is that really a problem, or it's just me (and that's alright if it's just me)? If it's a problem, how it should be handled?

Answer (score 15):

If you don't like these answers, don't vote for them.

However, the best answers are usually the ones that tell you how to solve your *actual* problem the best way. That might not always involve the tools you already know about. Teasing out what the *actual* problem is [is well discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) already.

The person asking the question is always free to clarify that they know about the suggested tool but have rejected it for other reasons. Answerers will (and should) assume the person asking the question simply doesn't *know* about the better tool unless they explicitly state they cannot use it.

Your example of *"how can I use sed to..."* being answered with *"use awk instead"* may be valid, but I'm sure there are many more cases where the asker has been very happy to receive advice directing them away from using the wrong tool for a given job. The classic example would be [people trying to use Regex for everything](https://www.google.ca/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22don't+use+regex%22) from jobs it's over qualified for (like splitting a string by a single character delimiter) to jobs it cannot do like parsing XML.

If somebody is trying to use a regular expression and a loop to split a string  `"a,b,c"` into an array `["a", "b", "c"]`, I'm pretty sure it's because they don't know about `split`/`explode`/whatever your language provides, because virtually every language provides a better way of doing this than regex.

Comment: There's a problem with this that I've experienced multiple times: it can create dead ends. I search for *X*, find a question asking for *X* and explaining the context, and see an answer saying "since you're doing [...] you can just use *Y* instead". Well, that's great and all for OP, but it's useless for me, my context is different, I really need *X*.

Comment: @Stijn Then your problem isn't actually the same as the old question. Ask a new question, and be sure to list your additional constraints. You can even link to the previous question and explicitly state why it is not a duplicate and that none of its answers are applicable.